Unwanted SVG Icons in Pagination Buttons with AdminLTE and Bootstrap in Laravel Project
I'm using AdminLTE with Bootstrap in my Laravel project, and I’m encountering an issue where SVG icons (left and right arrows) are appearing in my pagination buttons. These SVG icons seem to be different from the default pagination buttons shown in AdminLTE’s demo.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’m using Laravel's pagination, displaying it in my Blade file with



{{ $distributorStock->links() }}





<svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>




The pagination renders, but there are unexpected SVG icons inside
the "Previous" and "Next" buttons.
I’ve checked the bootstrap-4 pagination template, but the SVG icons
still appear.

What I’ve Tried:

Checked my CSS to ensure that no custom styles are forcing the SVG
icons to appear.
Tried to remove the SVG icons with display: none CSS, but it only
hides them without fixing the underlying issue.

My Question: Is there any way to prevent these SVG icons from appearing in the pagination buttons in AdminLTE? How can I ensure my pagination buttons look like the default AdminLTE pagination without SVG icons?
Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated!
[i Am Talkin About This Css][1]
enter image description here

i get the Answer
Use the


php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination



Cmd to Create the Bootstrap Vendor file for Pagination and Then i have change the


            <div class="mt-4">
                {{ $distributorStock->links() }}
            </div> 
        </div>



code to
this


  {{ $distributorStock->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4') }}



  {{ $distributorStock->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4') }}

then i get this  output 
